# How to enable deletion of logs in Loki / Grafana

Tags: asp.net, logging, grafana-loki

I am running a local instance of Loki in windows. Using a C# application i am able to send logs to Loki without any problem. The only issue i have is that logs are not being deleted. Not even chunks are being deleted.
By having this `.yaml` configuration:

```
auth_enabled: false

server:
  http_listen_port: 3100
  grpc_listen_port: 9096

common:
  instance_addr: 127.0.0.1
  path_prefix: /tmp/loki
  storage:
    filesystem:
      chunks_directory: /tmp/loki/chunks
      rules_directory: /tmp/loki/rules
  replication_factor: 1
  ring:
    kvstore:
      store: inmemory

query_range:
  results_cache:
    cache:
      embedded_cache:
        enabled: true
        max_size_mb: 100

compactor:
  working_directory: /tmp/loki/compactor
  retention_enabled: true
  retention_delete_delay: 5m
  retention_delete_worker_count: 150

limits_config:
  retention_period: 5m

schema_config:
  configs:
    - from: 2020-10-24
      store: boltdb-shipper
      object_store: filesystem
      schema: v11
      index:
        prefix: index_
        period: 24h

ruler:
  alertmanager_url: http://localhost:9093
# By default, Loki will send anonymous, but
```

I am expecting Loki to delete logs after 5 minutes when they are created (arrived and stored in chunks) but nothing happens. Please help me here to understand why loki is not deleting logs, actually i don't even know if this is possible to do in Loki. Imagine having a server for production that stores multiple logs... eventually the disk space will be full (and that can't happen, especially in a production environment).
I checked the Docs [here](https://grafana.com/docs/loki/latest/configuration/) but can't figure out how to set deletion of logs after a specific time period.

Answer (score 0):

The parameter `retention_delete_delay` is to delay deletions that result from enforcing log retention period the length of which is set in `retention_period`, see the documentation in https://grafana.com/docs/loki/latest/configure/#compactor . If you want your logs to be retained for 5 minutes you need to set both `retention_period` and `compaction_interval` to 5 minutes in your compactor config bloc. However compactors can only delete data that have been flushed from ingester memory, so you also need to reduce `max_chunk_age` to 5 minutes or less in your ingester config bloc.